# How to run React Web Application forever

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have created a web application using React framework. I am able to Run it in localhost using npm start command.

I have a server in AWS ubuntu 14.04. I have uploaded all code there and run the application using npm command. It is working well. But if i close the terminal then it has been stopped. I know we need to run that instance or service. But how can we do it forever without any UI of ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Did you link the public directory's file(HTMl/PHP file) to your dedicated host server? 
If not, Look to do how to setup it with AWS in local you can do it with virtual hosting. I'm sure in AWS there'll be any same way to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library called `forever` which will keep the process running in the background.

https://github.com/foreverjs/forever

Comment: yes but it is for Node.js. It does not work with React.

Comment: @SucbeSys `npm start` is executed by node the `n` in `npm` stands for `node`

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes looking for an answer here, I have one solution that worked for me. Using the package `forever` as mentioned in the answers on this question did not work when dealing with a react app. So, I created a service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=React Frontend Service

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/bin/node /home/user/project/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js
Restart=always
User=nobody
Group=nogroup
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/project/
Type=idle

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Copy the file (I named it `react-frontend.service`) to  `/etc/systemd/system/`, and start the service as:

```
sudo systemctl start react-frontend.service
```

You can check if the server is up by running `netstat -anp | grep 3000` to verify that node is listening for incoming connections on port 3000.